# Как задать путь для файла sqlite3 (android), чтобы он создавался на SD карте телефона?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

Приложение написано на python kivy. В ходе работы приложения создается файл database.db

`conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")`

Нужно чтобы он создавался на SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить условие перед запуском приложения:

```
if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

Путь к SD карте:

```
from jnius import autoclass
Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
path = join(f"{sdpath}", "database.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{path}")
```

В buildozer.spec добавить:

```
requirements = ...,android,jnius
```